# JQPL: Create new Object within the Query from multiple tables

Tags: java, database, jpa, jpql

I'm currently trying to fetch data with JQPL. My Query looks like

```
SELECT NEW com.test.CustomObject(t1.name, CASE WHEN(t2 IS NOT NULL) THEN true ELSE false END) FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = :id1 AND t2.id = :id2
```

Of course the two entities iteself exist an querying for one of them is working. Querying with a fixed value also works:

```
SELECT NEW com.test.CustomObject(t1.name, false) FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = :id1
```

My problem is, that I receive no return value if :id2 has a non existing value. Instead of giving false to the CustomObject constructor, the row itself is omitted completely.

What else could I do to gain knowledge if parameter id2 has a row in table2 to pass this as a boolean value to the custom constructor?

Further information can of course be provided.

Comment: Your code doesn't have a lot of sense. Please read carefully http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 to understand what is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: I tried to simplify my problem to the core of the problem and got rid of a lot of extra code that would otherwise make the whole query unreadable. I didn't really check for logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem with Exsists:

```
SELECT NEW com.test.CustomObject(t1.name, CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT t2.id FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = :id2) THEN true ELSE false END) FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = :id1
```

Comment: Further on digging in the problem i decided to go to Native Queries. If someone is interested leave a message

Answer (score 2):

You have to use LEFT (OUTER) JOIN to connect from table1 to table2. This will cause left hand side to be part of the result also when right hand side of join doesn't exists. In such a case values coming from the right hand side (for example t2.id) have null values.

Also it doesn't make sense to set id as a parameter twice (assuming what you want is t1.id=t2.id). Just use join and set id parameter once.

Comment: thank you for your response. The Problem is, that id1 is not id2 so putting t1.id = t2.id wouldn't do the trick. How would the Left Outer Join statement look like. I always thought, that I can Left Outer Join parts of previous Selects like SELECT ... FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t1.value value; What i would need would be something like SELECT ... FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2  - is that possible? would i specify the join condition in the where clause like WHERE t2.id = :id2?